# Can I change the SpaProxyLaunchCommand from program.cs in ASP .NET Core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I created an ASP.NET Core 6.0 with Angular Ap in Visual Studio

In the `.csproj` file you can find the property:

```
<SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
```

I want to change it to programmatically in `program.cs` like:

```
var startupLanguage = "en-US";
SpaProxyLaunchCommand = $"npm run start-{startupLanguage}";
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try editing the line? If yes, what happened?

Comment: @Rafalon yes it works fine but I want to change it programmatically in program.cs. See my updated question.